# Tweepy with stream hangs for follow tag

Tags: python, stream, tweepy

I am trying to run the Tweepy `StreamListener` to follow users' Tweets on Twitter.

When I use the `track` keyword it works, but when I add `follow='userid'` it hangs. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
stream_listener = StreamListener()
auth = OAuthHandler("", "")
auth.set_access_token("", "")
stream = Stream(auth=auth, listener=stream_listener)
#stream.filter(follow="")
api = tweepy.API(auth)
screen_name = "ThetaWarrior"
user = api.get_user(screen_name)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
print("User details:")
print(user.name)
print(user.description)
print(user.location)
print(user.id_str)
stream.filter(follow="98**************")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `follow` parameter needs to be a list of user IDs, not a string, e.g.:
`stream.filter(follow=["98**************"])`
assuming `"98**************"` is an actual user ID.

See [the Streaming with Tweepy section of the documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.10.0/streaming_how_to.html) for Tweepy v3.10 or [the documentation for `Stream.filter`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stream.html#tweepy.Stream.filter) for the latest development version of Tweepy on the master branch, set to be released as v4.0. Also see [the documentation for the POST statuses/filter endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter).